# How to distinguish capital letters from small letters in Java?

Tags: java, string, character, capitalization, capslock

I am a rather newer user for Java as I've only learned some recently within the last couple of months and have never done any real programming before, so please try to explain to me the terms that you are talking about if they are complicated or please redirect me to any other threads with explanations of what you are possibly talking about. So our of curiosity, for one of my programs, is there a way I can possibly write all the capital letters and lowercase letters, or do I have to type them all out?
Thanks,
Rishi

Comment: Show some expected inputs, expected outputs and what you've tried to so so far, please.

Comment: You are looking for [String.toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())?

Comment: Unclear; are you talking about capital case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
  Character.isUpperCase(Char ch)
  Character.isLowerCase(Char ch)
```

If you want write all capital letters

```
for(char c='A'; c<='Z';c++) {
            System.out.print(c+",");
}
```

All small letters

```
for(char c='a'; c<='z';c++) {
                System.out.print(c+",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it like this:

```
for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
        System.out.println(alphabet);
}
```

You can count chars. The value behind a char is the Ascii-Code.

http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm